# How can I write a power shell code to call a .sql file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a couple .sql scripts. I want to write a wrapper function/script to call and run all of those .sql files. It can be either in sql or powershell.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you mean by `either SQL or Powershell`? If you want to run in SQL, you can add all scripts(.sql) to stored proc.

Comment: I mean I need to write a script either with sql or powershell.

Comment: thanks. 
so what would be a sample code in my store proc ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "path_to_folder_with_scripts" -Filter "*.sql" | % {invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile $_.FullName}
```

Edit *path_to_folder_with_scripts* to your path to folder with sql files

Comment: This only shows the sql files in folder. I need to run them.

Comment: @kimitrio: that's what the pipe to invoke-sqlcmd does.